# Python: Add Integers together from a file, row by row

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want my program to work out the mean of some numbers, those numbers are stored in a .txt file `Integers.txt`. There are 98 numbers in total, each taking up 1 line. How would I be able to work out the mean, calling it "MeanLength".
Everything in the code below works, it's just I am struggling to find a way to add them together and then divide them by how many there are (Average).

This is my code:

```
def AddSongLengths():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("xxxxx.db")
    c=conn.cursor()
    PlaylistInput = input("Select which Playlist you want to calculate the mean of: ")
    Length = c.execute('SELECT "Length" FROM {0}'.format(PlaylistInput))
    file=open("Integers.txt", "w")
    for row in c.fetchall():
        TrackSeconds = TrackIntoSeconds("{0}".format(row[0]))
        file.writelines("""
        {0}""".format(TrackSeconds))
    file.close()
```

Comment: Research first, then post.  There are many questions and tutorials that will show you how to take the mean of a sequence of numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you want to compute the average of a list of integers and then append them to a file?

```
def AddSongLengths():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("xxxxx.db")
    c=conn.cursor()
    PlaylistInput = input("Select which Playlist you want to calculate the mean of: ")
    Length = c.execute('SELECT "Length" FROM {0}'.format(PlaylistInput))
    file=open("Integers.txt", "w")
    sum = 0
    count = 0
    for row in c.fetchall():
        TrackSeconds = TrackIntoSeconds("{0}".format(row[0]))
        file.writelines("""
        {0}""".format(TrackSeconds))
        try:
            sum += int(row[0])
            count += 1
    avg = sum / count
    file.writelines("{}".format(avg))
    file.close()
```

this should work - it might require a little debugging :)